# Modular property of affine algebra and conformal vertex algebra

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, vertex-algebras

I wonder how modular property naturally arises in conformal theory.
Is it obvious from physical viewpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- see Cardy's paper [Operator content of two-dimensional conformally invariant theories](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213%2886%2990552-3).  In a nutshell, the torus partition function of a conformal theory can be computed using a transfer matrix in several ways.  The equivalence of these different calculations is the modular invariance of the torus partition function.